# Error while accessing json key

Tags: php, json

I have the following json data

```
Merchant_stripe_response Object
(
    [_response:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
            [object] => customer
            [created] => 1387883058
            [id] => cus_3BFTkHufSbD1I9
            [livemode] => 
            [description] => Order #22
            [email] => 
            [delinquent] => 
            [metadata] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [subscription] => 
            [discount] =>
```

I am trying to get the value in the key description. I tried doing this

```
echo $_response->description
```

but I got an error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Merchant_stripe_response::$_response in C:\wamp\
```

I also tried json_decode to use `echo $response['description']` but it returned blank json.

Did I do something wrong? How can I access a key with this structure?

```
[_response:protected]
```

Comment: "but I got an error" what error?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Merchant_stripe_response::$_response in C:\wamp\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's most likely a reason that it's protected - because you're not supposed to access it directly. Is there perhaps a function called `getDescription()` or a similar getter?

Alternately, again - I don't encourage this, as there's probably a reason as to why you can't, you could extend the class:

```
class Merchant_stripe_response_custom extends Merchant_stripe_response {
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->_response->description;
    }
}
```

It seems that there isn't a getter (source code [here](https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/master/libraries/merchant/merchant_stripe.php)), so you'd have to do the above, or simply change `protected` to `public` in their source code (or add the getter in there).

Comment: It is something related to Stripe payment gateway... Does making protected to public cause any serious security issues?